# Deterministic random function

Tags: python, function, random, integer, deterministic

I'm developing a little script using **Python 3.6**. I have a question.
If I have a range of number (for example a range of number between 1 and n)
and I would like to create a function that, taken as input `x` some integer value (whatever it is), it returns a randomly chosen value between 1 and n, 
but this value must **always be the same until the input `x` remains the same**!
I don't know how to do this (I think it's simple).
If I create the function like this:

```
def random_determ(x):
   return random.randint(1, n)
```

obviously it doesn't work because the random choice doesn't depend in any way on `x`.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the number is determined by the input, it isn't very random. I would suggest looking into hashes and how they take an input and deterministically turn it into a number.

Comment: Can I assume that when you say "this value must always be the same until the input x remains the same", you mean "this value must always be the same as long as the input x remains the same"?

Comment: @Kevin Yes exactly